# Api Json Data Not Show

Tags: php, json, api, parsing, wordpress-rest-api

hi i'm having problems in showing json data taken via request to an external api rest. I am using wordpress to make requests and the json file is returned without errors and so everything it's ok. When I try to insert data in an html table nothing is displayed. Below I insert the returned json and php code I am using.

JSON

```
object(stdClass)#5501 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["data"]=> array(12) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5562 (7) { ["sport_key"]=> string(26) "soccer_turkey_super_league" ["sport_nice"]=> string(19) "Turkey Super League" ["teams"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "Denizlispor" [1]=> string(16) "Yeni Malatyaspor" } ["commence_time"]=> int(1604831497) ["home_team"]=> string(16) "Yeni Malatyaspor" ["sites"]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5641 (4) { ["site_key"]=> string(10) "paddypower" ["site_nice"]=> string(11) "Paddy Power" ["last_update"]=> int(1604835079) ["odds"]=> object(stdClass)#5643 (1) { ["h2h"]=> array(3) { [0]=> float(31) [1]=> float(1.06) [2]=> float(10) } } } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5647 (4) { ["site_key"]=> string(7) "betfair" ["site_nice"]=> string(7) "Betfair" ["last_update"]=> int(1604835077) ["odds"]=> object(stdClass)#5648 (2) { ["h2h"]=> array(3) { [0]=> float(26) [1]=> float(1.12) [2]=> float(10.5) } ["h2h_lay"]=> array(3) { [0]=> float(55) [1]=> float(1.13) [2]=> float(13) } } } ......``
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
add_shortcode( 'external_data', 'callback_function_name' );

function callback_function_name(){
    
    
$url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx&apiKey=xxxxxxxxx';

$arguments = array(

'method' => 'GET',  

);

$response = wp_remote_get($url, $arguments);

if ( is_wp_error($response)) {
    
$error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    
return "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    
}

$results = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ));

//var_dump($results);

$html .='';
$html .= '<table>';

$html .='<tr>';
$html .='<td>Exemple<td>';
$html .='<td>Exemple<td>';
$html .='<td>Exemple<td>';
$html .='<td>Exemple<td>';
$html .='<td>Exemple<td>';
$html .='</tr>';


foreach( $results as $result ){
    
$html .='<tr>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->data . '<td>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->sport_key . '<td>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->sport_nice . '<td>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->teams . '<td>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->commence_time . '<td>';
$html .='</tr>';


}

$html .='</table>';

return $html;


}


?>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ... your installation is specific to you. try ````var_dump($html);```` at the end and see if your resulting html code is fine, then update your question.

Comment: hi, no your solution not work...

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the whole JSON response directly, but instead you should be accessing `data` in the results for your `foreach` loop.

Change your `foreach` loop to this,

```
foreach( $results['data'] as $result ){
    
$html .='<tr>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->sport_key . '<td>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->sport_nice . '<td>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->teams . '<td>';
$html .='<td>' . $result->commence_time . '<td>';
$html .='</tr>';

}
```

Since all the data you need is under `data`. This is the format of your JSON (as much as I was able to get from your question.)

You will not be able to print `$result->teams` directly as well since its an array.

You should use a [JSON beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) to check the response and know how the data is structed in the JSON before trying to decode it.

```
object(stdClass)#5501 (2) {
  ["success"]=> bool(true) 
  ["data"]=> array(12) { 
      [0]=> object(stdClass)#5562 (7) { 
         ["sport_key"]=> string(26) "soccer_turkey_super_league" 
         ["sport_nice"]=> string(19) "Turkey Super League" 
         ["teams"]=> array(2) { 
             [0]=> string(11) "Denizlispor" 
             [1]=> string(16) "Yeni Malatyaspor" } 
         ["commence_time"]=> int(1604831497) 
         ["home_team"]=> string(16) "Yeni Malatyaspor" 
         ["sites"]=> array(4) {
             [0]=> object(stdClass)#5641 (4) { 
               ["site_key"]=> string(10) "paddypower" 
               ["site_nice"]=> string(11) "Paddy Power" 
               ["last_update"]=> int(1604835079) 
               ["odds"]=> object(stdClass)#5643 (1) { 
                      ["h2h"]=> array(3) { 
                          [0]=> float(31) 
                          [1]=> float(1.06) 
                          [2]=> float(10) } 
               } 
             }....
```